# How to get rid of the in place FutureWarning when setting an entire column from an array?

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas v.1.5.0 [a new warning has been added](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/whatsnew/v1.5.0.html#inplace-operation-when-setting-values-with-loc-and-iloc), which is shown, when a column is set from an array of different dtype. The `FutureWarning` informs about a planned semantic change, when using `iloc`: the change will be done in-place in future versions. The [changelog](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/whatsnew/v1.5.0.html#inplace-operation-when-setting-values-with-loc-and-iloc) instructs what to do to get the old behavior, but there is no hint how to handle the situation, when in-place operation is in fact the right choice.

The example from the changelog:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'price': [11.1, 12.2]}, index=['book1', 'book2'])
original_prices = df['price']
new_prices = np.array([98, 99])
df.iloc[:, 0] = new_prices
df.iloc[:, 0]
```

This is the warning, which is printed in pandas 1.5.0:

> FutureWarning: In a future version, `df.iloc[:, i] = newvals` will
> attempt to set the values inplace instead of always setting a new
> array. To retain the old behavior, use either `df[df.columns[i]] = newvals` or, if columns are non-unique, `df.isetitem(i, newvals)`

How to get rid of the warning, if I don't care about in-place or not, but want to get rid of the warning? Am I supposed to change dtype explicitly? Do I really need to catch the warning every single time I need to use this feature? Isn't there a better way?

Comment: Why not replacing `df.iloc[:, 0] = new_prices` with `df[df.columns[0]] = new_prices`, as the warning message suggests?

Comment: @Laurent because there is no reason for me to retain the old behavior.

Comment: The warning is confusing, as the change apply to both loc and iloc - https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.5.0.html#inplace-operation-when-setting-values-with-loc-and-iloc

Comment: You can make a regex to ignore the warning using the `warnings` module. For example, `warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', '[\s\w\W]*non-unique[\s\w\W]*', FutureWarning)`

Comment: @OluwafemiSule see my own answer below, that's basically what I did.

Comment: Oh, I see. I had this question opened for a long time and I didn't notice the update.

Comment: This warning has gone away in pandas 2.0.

Comment: This behavior is super annoying, if you *want* the new behavior (or don't care) there seems to be no way to tell it to use the new behavior (or just don't warn).  In my case I'm using `df.loc[bool_vec, 'column'] = ...` and if `bool_vec` is all `True`s, I get the warning.  Meaning I can't just switch to the `__setitem__()` technique.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't found any better way than suppressing the warning using the `warnings` module:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import warnings

df = pd.DataFrame({"price": [11.1, 12.2]}, index=["book1", "book2"])
original_prices = df["price"]
new_prices = np.array([98, 99])
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    # Setting values in-place is fine, ignore the warning in Pandas >= 1.5.0
    # This can be removed, if Pandas 1.5.0 does not need to be supported any longer.
    # See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74057367/859591
    warnings.filterwarnings(
        "ignore",
        category=FutureWarning,
        message=(
            ".*will attempt to set the values inplace instead of always setting a new array. "
            "To retain the old behavior, use either.*"
        ),
    )

    df.iloc[:, 0] = new_prices

df.iloc[:, 0]
```

Comment: In my case it seems to be spitting out a `DeprecationWarning` instead of `FutureWarning`, so I just removed the `category` argument.

Comment: @KenWilliams oh interesting. What Pandas version did you use?

Answer (score 6):

As the changelog states, the warning is printed when setting an entire column from an array *with different dtype*, so adjusting the dtype is one way to silence it:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'price': [11.1, 12.2]}, index=['book1', 'book2'])
original_prices = df['price']
new_prices = np.array([98, 99]).astype(float)
df.iloc[:, 0] = new_prices
df.iloc[:, 0]
```

Note the additional `.astype(float)`. Not an ideal solution, but a solution.

Comment: Why not just use `[98.0, 99.0]` instead of `[98, 99]`? Then you don't need the `.astype(float)`.

Comment: Because the `.astype(float)` method is what you would do in a real-life example, where `[98, 99]` is replaced with an array `x` with unknown entries.

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured this out. I was using this pattern

```
df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

to make columns 1 and greater numeric. What seems to trigger the warning is when I'm converting a column in place to a different dtype.But if I switch to:

```
df[df.columns[1:]] = df[df.columns[1:]].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

then all is good. The secret I think is that I'm avoiding the use of `.loc[]`. In my particular case, I ended up using a variant of this

```
df[df.columns[1:]] = df[df.columns[1:]].astype(float)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade your pandas vision >= 2.0.

`python -m pip install --upgrade pandas`

Comment: this clearly goes against what the warning says, and the user who asked may end up with a pandas version which has already deprecated that feature

Answer (score -1):

I am just filtering all future warnings for now:

```py
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter("ignore", category=FutureWarning)
```

Comment: I don't think this is good practice, especially not in code imported elsewhere. The warnings are there for a reason, so just silencing all of them without checking might be dangerous.

Comment: Wouldn't this "good practice" depend on application?  Sometimes a notebook is built for a client in which the client would then see such warnings which is useless to the client and might cause unnecessary concern.  The dev/analyst/scientist can easily turn off the silencing of warnings when working on the code.

Answer (score -1):

```
# Ignore future warnings

import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message="errors='ignore' is deprecated")
```