# Pandas dataframe upsert: FutureWarning when doing dataframe.update on dataframe containing datetime series/columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to update one dataframe with data from another dataframe.  in most cases this works fine.  however when the dataframes contain at least one column of type datetime64, i get a FutureWarning.

This simplified code that replicates the issue:

```
    import pandas as pd
    index = pd.to_datetime(['01/03/2022', '01/04/2022'])
    data1 ={'value': pd.to_datetime(['01/05/2022', '01/06/2022'])}
    data2 ={'value': pd.to_datetime(['01/05/2022', '01/07/2022'])}

    df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data1,  index=index)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data2,  index=index)
    df1.update(df2)
```

And the warning:

```
FutureWarning: In a future version, `df.iloc[:, i] = newvals` will attempt to set the values inplace instead of always setting a new array. To retain the old behavior, use either `df[df.columns[i]] = newvals` or, if columns are non-unique, `df.isetitem(i, newvals)`
  df1.update(df2)
```

This only happens for dataframes where one of the columns/series is of type datetime64
The recommendation in the warning on how to avoid doesnt seem like an really good solution in my case as i may have a variable number of columns (often i wont know about them).  To that end..some questions:

1. IS there a recommended way to solve this problem EFFICIENTLY.
2. or can i ignore this warning.
3. Do these warnings cause performance issues with code if there are many of them

Comment: Related to https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/48673

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get rid of the in place FutureWarning when setting an entire column from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74057367/how-to-get-rid-of-the-in-place-futurewarning-when-setting-an-entire-column-from)

Comment: yeah...it seems @Alecg_O provides a link showing this is actually more of core issue or bug. in some cases, this warning doesnt make sense.

Comment: this warning has disappeared in pandas 2.0